# How can I adapt the following datatable script code which uses checkbox all to my asp.net core app?

Tags: javascript, razor, checkbox, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

Recently, I installed the Datatable library in my Asp.net app, and is very useful!

I wanted one of my Datatables to have a "Checkbox all" that when pressed, would mark all the existing checkboxes in the current rows of the table which are filtered, and aslo I wanted that all of those checkboxes were part of a group with a name attribute assigned. And when searching, I found a already-made Script that does just what I want!

This one: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/

but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how the heck I should adapt this script to my app environment. Since I use a Model instead of ajax/json?, and unlike the link code, I want to put a checkbox manually in each td row of my table, instead of making them appear in an empty "td", as the link code does (thing I don't understand exactly how the code does it).

Can someone help me adapt the code made by gyrocode too my app? Thank you very much in advance.

My view code without gyrocode's jquery datable script:

```
@model IEnumerable<Co.Models.Com>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card level-3">
        <h3>List</h3>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/DataTables/datatables.min.css" />

        <div>
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered select" id="tabla">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
                        <th>
                            <div>Nomb</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div>Fech</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div>AAA</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div>Tuuu</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div>Hor</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div>Mino</div>
                        </th>
                        <th><div></div></th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <th><div></div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="group" value=@item.Id type="checkbox">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fech)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aombr)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tip)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hor)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tooo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                EDIT
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                DETAILS
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                DELETE
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#tabla").dataTable({

        responsive: true,

        buttons: [
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
    });
</scrip>
```

Jquery Datatable: https://datatables.net/download/

(PD: yes, I tried to just change my table Id from "tabla" to "example", but that wasn't enough to make the code work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For how to apply gyrocode's code to your code,you could check the following code.And be sure change `$("#tabla").dataTable({})` to `$("#tabla").DataTable({})`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>          
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table) {
    var $table = table.table().node();
    var $chkbox_all = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
    var $chkbox_checked = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
    var chkbox_select_all = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

    // If none of the checkboxes are checked
    if ($chkbox_checked.length === 0) {
        chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
        if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
            chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
        }

        // If all of the checkboxes are checked
    } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length) {
        chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
        if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
            chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
        }

        // If some of the checkboxes are checked
    } else {
        chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
        if ('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all) {
            chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Array holding selected row IDs
    var rows_selected = [];
    var table = $("#tabla").DataTable({

        responsive: true,

        buttons: [
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
    });

    // Handle click on checkbox
    $('#tabla tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

        // Get row data
        var data = table.row($row).data();

        // Get row ID
        var rowId = data[0];

        // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs 
        var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected);

        // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
        if (this.checked && index === -1) {
            rows_selected.push(rowId);

            // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
        } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1) {
            rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
        }

        if (this.checked) {
            $row.addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $row.removeClass('selected');
        }

        // Update state of "Select all" control
        updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);

        // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Handle click on table cells with checkboxes
    $('#tabla').on('click', 'tbody td, thead th:first-child', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
    });

    // Handle click on "Select all" control
    $('thead input[name="select_all"]', table.table().container()).on('click', function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#tabla tbody input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
        } else {
            $('#tabla tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
        }

        // Prevent click event from propagating to parent
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Handle table draw event
    table.on('draw', function () {
        // Update state of "Select all" control
        updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Rena thank you. There is only one problem, and that is that the "checkbox all" only selects all the visible rows that meet the criteria of the search, on the current table page (pagination), when the behavior that I expect is that the all checkbox select all the rows, which currently exist in the datable, regardless of whether they are in another pagination or not the one I am seeing, but these are filtered by what was searched in the input.

I just noticed that the script I posted has the same behavior? Ok, sorry I hadn't noticed that. Do you think this pagination issue can be fixed?

Comment: Hi @DiegoErrázuriz,not clear about how do you want to do your pagination,did you want to check the `select all` checkbox,then all the pagination's checkbox should be checked? And I find what's wrong with your previous code and have updated the answer by using your shared link.